# Checking whether a plugged in device is hotpluggable or not using udev

Tags: python, udev, hal, pyudev

I  have a python script to get plugged in device  details. I am using udev library to manage the connected devices.

**From my python script I want to check whether the plugged in device is hotpluggable or not. How can I find this using udev library.**

Earlier I was using HAL library to manage device. In HAL I was able to get this information from 'storage.hotpluggable' property of HAL device.

Please help. Thanks in advance....

Comment: available properties depend on the `subsystem`. what is your specific use case?

Comment: I want all the block devices that is having hotpluggable property value is true. For a device I want to check the hotpluggable behaviour